# How to run exe under command line by the web service deployed on IIS 8?

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have deployed a web service on IIS 8, the web service need to run some .exe utility tools by using command line console. It works perfectly on localhost, but it does not work when I use web browser to access it remotely. the exe did not get call at all. I did some research on internet, someone mentioned it is IIS user permission problem which I created a new account with full control permission, someone mentioned that is because application pool has different permission with the web service(which I checked it is not the case).Someone said it might because the exe file is 32 bit application so I enabled the 32 bit application run in application pool. However, none of above fixed my problem. I was wondering if I missed anything?Thanks for any help.

some updates, I have also changed the handler mapping on IIS to enable the Execute exe(under edit feature permission). The exe file I need to call is from a third party company. Now I can run system method like "dir *.*", "ping xx.xx.xx.xx" with now problem, but not this exe file.

Comment: I fixed that, it happened to be a third-party software problem. I recommend you check the permission of your web service under IIS first(make sure the account- IUSR has full control permission level), then check if the 32 bit application run in application pool has been enabled. don't forget check if the handler mapping configured correctly as I mention in my question. At last, you may contact your third-party software producer for information.